# Building tree like structure for feeding Freemarker from JDBC

Tags: jdbc, groovy, freemarker

I want to generate code with Groovy and Freemarker (especially [GFreeMarker](http://groovy.codehaus.org/GFreeMarker)) - I want to generate a Java wrapper for calling stored procedures. So I query ORACLE with this statement:

```
select PACKAGE_NAME, OBJECT_NAME, POSITION, ARGUMENT_NAME, DATA_TYPE, IN_OUT
from USER_ARGUMENTS
```

This data is denormalized (each parameter is on a line) and hierarchical:

```
- Package (PACKAGE_NAME)
  - Function (OBJECT_NAME)
    - Arguments (ARGUMENT_NAME, DATA_TYPE, IN_OUT)
```

I want to store it into an hierarchical structure to feed it to Freemarker to generate code. This means that for every row I have to create a new Package instance or select an existing on, then create a new Function instance or select an existing one and create a new argument.

Can this be done via an [ObjectGraphBuilder](http://groovy.codehaus.org/ObjectGraphBuilder) or should I go into a combination with maps and lists?
How is this done in a "groovy way"? Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Groovy or not, I did it the following way, please provide better answers and I will accept it!

First I build the following structure:

```java
Map packages = new LinkedHashMap()  

class Package {
    String name
    Map functions = [:]
}

class Function {
    String name
    String returnType
    boolean isFunction = false
    Map parameters = [:]
}

class Parameter {
    String name
    String dataType
    String inOut
}
```

Then I read it with

```java
sql.eachRow("""\
    select PACKAGE_NAME, OBJECT_NAME, POSITION, ARGUMENT_NAME, DATA_TYPE, IN_OUT
    from USER_ARGUMENTS
    order by PACKAGE_NAME, OBJECT_NAME, POSITION""")
{
    // create or get package
    def thePackage = packages[it.PACKAGE_NAME ?: '']
    if (thePackage == null) {
        thePackage = new Package(name : it.PACKAGE_NAME ?: '')
        packages[it.PACKAGE_NAME ?: ''] = thePackage
    }

    // create or get function
    def theFunction = thePackage.functions[it.OBJECT_NAME ?: '']
    if (theFunction == null) {
        theFunction = new Function(name: it.OBJECT_NAME ?: '')
        thePackage.functions[it.OBJECT_NAME ?: ''] = theFunction
    }


    // Position 0 is the return value
    if (it.POSITION == 0) {
        theFunction.isFunction = true
        theFunction.returnType = it.DATA_TYPE
    }
    else {
        // create the argument 
        def theParameter = new Parameter(
            name: it.ARGUMENT_NAME, dataType: it.DATA_TYPE, inOut: it.IN_OUT)
        theFunction.parameters[it.ARGUMENT_NAME ?: ''] = theParameter
    }
}
```